# Recovering the n'th pickled item from a file without reading the first n-1 items

Tags: python, file-io, pickle

As the title says, I want to store a sequence of objects in a pickle file, and retrieve the `n'th` item from this sequence.

Here is some code that does it:

```
import pickle
import os

filename = 'my_file.pkl'

if os.path.exists(filename):
    os.remove(filename)

# Write things to file
things = [{'thing0': 0}, {'thing1': 1}, {'thing2': 2}]
for thing in things:
    with open(filename, 'ab') as f:
        pickle.dump(thing, f)


def get_nth_item(filename, n):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for i in range(n+1):
            obj = pickle.load(f)
    return obj


# Read things back
assert get_nth_item(filename, 0) == {'thing0': 0}
assert get_nth_item(filename, 1) == {'thing1': 1}
assert get_nth_item(filename, 2) == {'thing2': 2}
```

But it is quite inefficient because I have to scan through the whole file up to that item first.

Is there a nice way to retrieve the item without having to read all the previous items first?

Comment: are all objects of same lengh?

Comment: Not necessarily